# How to implement a property changed notification without making an explicit call?

Tags: c#-4.0, inotifypropertychanged

In WPF there is the concept of two-way data binding, where when an object property value is updated in the db, it the framework also updates the view when the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is implemented.

I'm looking for something like this functionality in C# but not using WPF.

The scenario is that when an object property is updated, a series of notifications are sent to the other consumers of this object, notifying them of the property change.

So the flow is:

1. Update the database
2. Notify consumer 1
3. Notify consumer 2

This process requires three separate lines.  Is there a way to implement the WPF concept of a property changed to update whoever the consumers are (say, event-driven) without needing to explicitly notify the consumers?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing, what exactly are you trying to make a win-forms application, an ASP.NET webforms or MVC application, or what? each has a different set of ways to handle things like this which is why I am asking.

Comment: @Nomad101 - Ah yes... the underlying architecture is MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you are simply raising an event whenever you want to let consumers know that the property has changed. You only make one call to raise the event regardless of how many consumers are listening to that event.

If what you're trying to achieve is reduce boilerplate code, i.e. have only one line of code per setter, you can have a look at [this simple solution](http://ihadthisideaonce.com/2012/05/30/tip-modern-inotifypropertychanged/), which [can be made even nicer with C# 5](http://danrigby.com/2012/03/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way/).

Comment: Just to clarify, your suggestions are for non-WPF/non-Silverlight clients, correct?

Comment: This applies to any C# class regardless. It's true that WPF, Silverlight and WinForms use this interface to know when to update the UI, and this is the main reason why people usually implement this interface, but you can also implement it just for your own use.